# Does the drive circuit for a piezo buzzer require extra power?

Tags: oscillator, piezo-buzzer

I want to power a small piezo buzzer with a battery, and I am trying to work out the power requirements. 
The buzzer has a Rated Voltage of 3V, and the battery has a Nominal Voltage of 3V.
The buzzer is an external drive type which needs a drive circuit, and I am not sure how this circuit is going to effect the power requirements. A sample circuit is shown here.
[image: buzzer drive circuit]

http://www.microbuzzer.com/smt-smd-buzzer-basic-drive-circuits

Does this constitute an Oscillator Circuit?
Is the transistor, resistor and diode in the circuit going to increase the power requirements for the whole circuit. Can I still use a 3V battery, or does it need to have a higher voltage? 
(I am a novice when it comes to Electrical Engineering, as you might have noticed!)

Extra info about the buzzer and the battery just in case

The buzzer has a Rated Voltage of 3V, an Operating Voltage of 1~25V, a Rated Current ≤3mA, and a Generated Frequency of 4000Hz ± 500.

The battery has a Nominal Voltage of 3V, and End point Voltage of 2V, a Standard Current of 0.1 mA, a Continuous Current(Max) of 0.2 mA, and a Pulse Current(Max) of 5mA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Does the circuit shown represent an oscillator circuit?**

No, it doesn't.

This [Murata catalog](http://www.murata.com/products/catalog/pdf/p15e.pdf) provides several sample oscillator schematics for driving external-drive piezos, in Figure 6. The document overall makes good reading as an introduction to piezo buzzers and sound components.

---

**Will the battery be able to supply sufficient power?**

The buzzer and its drive circuitry together would typically consume just about the rated 3 mA of the piezo element itself on average - those ratings are usually on the worst-case side.

What will happen though is current spikes of as much as 8-10 times that value, as the piezo, which acts like a capacitor, charges up each time the transistor turns on. Those spikes are of very tiny duration, but if the battery in question cannot supply that current, the buzzer's volume will drop: Basically the piezo will not be able to charge up fully (again the capacitor analogy) before the next pulse hits it.

From the specifications stated for the battery, it seems **unlikely to be able to drive such a buzzer**: 0.2 mA continuous current is pretty low compared to what the buzzer + oscillator will demand, which is likely to be 3 mA or thereabouts.